# ASP.NET Identity Password Validation

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

I am using Identity in my MVC project, and it's all well and nice. Except the fact that the form for registering a new user has some crazy password requirements

> Passwords must have at least one non letter or digit character. Passwords must have at least one digit `('0'-'9')`. Passwords must have at least one uppercase `('A'-'Z')`.

**And here is the register model**

```
public class RegisterViewModel
{
    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "First Name")]
    public string FirstName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(50, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 2)]
    [Display(Name = "Last Name")]
    public string LastName { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [EmailAddress]
    [Display(Name = "Email")]
    public string Email { get; set; }

    [Required]
    [StringLength(100, ErrorMessage = "The {0} must be at least {2} characters long.", MinimumLength = 6)]
    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Passord")]
    public string Password { get; set; }

    [DataType(DataType.Password)]
    [Display(Name = "Repeat Password")]
    [Compare("Password", ErrorMessage = "The password and confirmation password do not match.")]
    public string ConfirmPassword { get; set; }
}
```

**Account Controller**

```
    // POST: /Account/Register
    [HttpPost]
    [AllowAnonymous]
    [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
    public async Task<ActionResult> Register(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        if (ModelState.IsValid)
        {
            var user = new ApplicationUser { UserName = model.Email, Email = model.Email };
            var result = await UserManager.CreateAsync(user, model.Password);
            if (result.Succeeded)
            {
                await SignInManager.SignInAsync(user, isPersistent:false, rememberBrowser:false);
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }
            AddErrors(result);
        }

        // If we got this far, something failed, redisplay form
        return View(model);
    }
```

I see the length requirement for the password, but I don't understand how to change the password validation so I don't need a non letter or digit character.

All help greatly appreciated, thank you.

Bonus: What does the `{0}` and `{2}` mean? Thank you.

Comment: that validation is probably in your `AccountController` somewhere.

Comment: Search your project for "RequireNonLetterOrDigit" and see [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796454/how-to-change-password-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-identity-2?rq=1). Bonus: that is a format string with two placeholders for the 0th and 2nd parameter passed to that format.

Comment: Here's a more complete [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13425320/what-parameters-does-the-stringlength-attribute-errormessage-take) for the format string.

Answer (score 17):

In `Startup.cs` where you add the Identity Service you can add options for password validation:

```
services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(Configuration, 
    options => 
        options.Password = new PasswordOptions 
        { 
            RequireDigit = true, 
            RequiredLength = 6, 
            RequireLowercase = true, 
            RequireUppercase = true, 
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false 
        })
[...];
```

Comment: This is what I needed using the ASP.NET Core Web Application (.NET Core) project template with Individual User Accounts.

Comment: I changed this - no effect it still enforces the same password requirements

Answer (score 10):

If you are using one of the ASP.NET template applications and have selected Authentication as 'Individual User Accounts' you will find the password options in a IdentityConfig.cs file in the App_Start folder in your application. Here you can change the password options as follows to turn off all requirements except the password length:

```
manager.PasswordValidator = new PasswordValidator
        {
            RequiredLength = 6,
            RequireNonLetterOrDigit = false,
            RequireDigit = false,
            RequireLowercase = false,
            RequireUppercase = false,
        };
```

Comment: dose somebody know how we can change error message to another language?