# asp.net core mvc password validators

Tags: c#, asp.net, validation, asp.net-core-mvc, user-accounts

What is the easy way to customize password validation rules in asp.net core MVC? The problem is exactly like someone had here [How To Change Password Validation in ASP.Net MVC Identity 2?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24796454/how-to-change-password-validation-in-asp-net-mvc-identity-2/24819318#24819318) the only difference is that I'm using **asp.net CORE MVC** (latest build) with Visual Studio 2015. I'd like to remove all password validation rules. There is no `ApplicationUserManager` class in the project, also I'm not sure if it's possible to customize UserManager validation rules in the `Startup.cs` file.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

If you want simply disable some password restrictions (RequireLowercase, RequiredLength etc) - configure `IdentityOptions.Password` in Startup, like this:

```
services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(o =>
{
    o.Password.RequiredLength = 12;
});
```

If you want completely change password validation logic - implement [`IPasswordValidator`](https://github.com/aspnet/Identity/blob/1.0.0/src/Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity/IPasswordValidator.cs) and register it in Startup.

Answer (score 14):

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
     services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>(options =>
            {
                options.Password.RequireDigit = true;
                options.Password.RequireLowercase = true;
                options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = true;
                options.Password.RequireUppercase = true;
                options.Password.RequiredLength = 6;
                options.User.AllowedUserNameCharacters = null;
            })
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<ApplicationDbContext>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();
}
```

Note: You should also change your new settings in **RegisterViewModel.Password,  ResetPasswordViewModel.Password,  ChangePasswordViewModel.NewPassword and  SetPasswordViewModel.NewPassword.**
to enable the new validation on front end.

Answer (score 2):

Also you can use a public class to customize your errors messages. Like this:

```
public class CustomIdentityErrorDescriber : IdentityErrorDescriber
{
    public override IdentityError PasswordRequiresDigit()
    {
        return new IdentityError
        {
            Code = nameof(PasswordRequiresDigit),
            Description = "Your personal describe error message here."
        };
    }

}
```

In your Statup.cs, in ConfigureService add:

```
public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
{
    services.AddIdentity<ApplicationUser, IdentityRole>()
            .AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>()
            .AddErrorDescriber<CustomIdentityErrorDescriber>()
            .AddDefaultTokenProviders();

     //...
}
```

Comment: Even though the question was about password validation and not messages, this is still useful. And to anyone who will be using this, you only need a single class and inside override every error describer you want to customize, a single .`AddErrorDescriber<ClassName>()` as well